# How to go about designing a quiz that changes difficulty based on user performance?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, statistics, python, computer-games

I thought about using a machine learning algorithm to learn the performance patterns of the quiz taker and model the next quiz based on how he/she performed. So each question will have a difficulty level on a scale of 1 to 10 and a score will be calculated ( scaled score ( out of the number of questions in each quiz ) and a raw score based on the difficulty values ) That's all I've got. I am very new to machine learning as a whole and I don't know how to proceed from here like which algorithm to use and how to go about it and so on. The front end part of the quiz has been written in python.

Comment: Using machine learning here is an overkill. Use an ad hoc heuristic instead.

Comment: Can you be edit the question to be clearer about what you mean by "learn the performance patterns of the quiz taker" and "model the next quiz"?  What do you want the algorithm to output?  Are you trying to make a prediction of some sort?  If so, what are you trying to predict?  As it stands the question is too vague for me to tell what kind of answer you are looking for.